# Json-Schema: reference property of enum of objects

Tags: jsonschema

I have a list of allowed objects (enum) and want to reference them in another object only by one of their properties.

Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "favoriteFruit": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/fruit/name"
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "fruit": {
      "enum": [
        {
          "name": "apple",
          "color": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "banana",
          "color": "yellow"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Should validate:

```
{
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
}
```

But the referencing with `"$ref": "#/$defs/fruit/name"` doesn't seem to be allowed. How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Enums only accept string values.</strike>

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "favoriteFruit": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/fruit"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "fruit": {
      "enum": [
        "apple",
        "banana"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The way you've defined your usage of enum and the expectation that `favoriteFruit: apple` will return an object schema is not possible

Other notable updates to your schema,

- `$defs` was only introduced in draft 2019-0, seeing you used draft-07, the correct property is `definitions`.
- The uri for draft-07 is `http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#`

If you want to define multiple objects for `favoriteFruit`, `oneOf` or `anyOf` may be suitable

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "favoriteFruit": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/fruit"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "fruit": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
           "properties": { 
              "name": {
                 "const": "apple"
               },
               "color": {
                 "const": "red"
               }
            },
           "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
           "properties": { 
              "name": {
                 "const": "banana"
               },
               "color": {
                 "const": "yellow"
               }
           },
           "additionalProperties": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

where a passing instance would be

```json
{ 
  "favoriteFruit": {
     "name": "apple",
     "color": "red"
  }
}
```

Comment: "Enums only accept string values." This is not correct. Enum values can be of any type, including objects.

Comment: ah...didn't catch that.  thanks for clarifying